# Why does msbuild try to copy from wrong path?

Tags: msbuild, windows-store-apps

I try to build Windows Store app using MSBuild.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>MSBuild.exe /t:build /p:Configurat
ion=Release;Platform=x86 E:\MyApp.W8.csproj /logger:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=E:/log/test.txt /p:OutputPath=E:/result
```

And I got this error:

> "E:\MyApp.W8.csproj
>       " (build target) (1) ->
>       (CopyGeneratedXaml target) ->
>         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v12.0\8.1\Microsoft.Wind
>       ows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(476,9): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "obj\x86\
>       Release\E:\MyApp.Shared\App.xbf" to "E:\result\E:\MyApp.Shared\App.xbf". The given path's format is not
>   supported. [E:\MyApp.W8.csproj]

I don`t know why MSBuild tries to use

```
obj\x86\Release\E:\MyApp.Shared\App.xbf
instead obj\x86\Release\App.xbf
```

or absolute path to App.xbf.

Comment: That OutputPath property got pretty mangled.  Hard to see how that happened, you'd have to post the detailed build trace to get a guess.  The forward slashes in the path name is a red flag, the proper one on Windows is a backslash.  But doesn't go wrong when I try it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have found a decision. I try to use MSBuild from another location. MSBuild from VS and it compiles everything correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://forum.ncrunch.net/yaf_postsm5721_NCrunch-Failing-to-comple--Windows-and--WindowsPhone-projects-inside-Universal-Application-solution.aspx#post5721), inside your .projitems file you'll find the following code:

```
<ApplicationDefinition Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)App.xaml">
<SubType>Designer</SubType>
</ApplicationDefinition>
```

Replace this with:

```
<ApplicationDefinition Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)App.xaml">
<SubType>Designer</SubType>
<Link>App.xaml</Link>
</ApplicationDefinition>
```